# How to tell if a weapon is one or two-handed

Tags: diablo-iii, ps3

This is probably a noob question but I don't see any consistent indication on whether a particular weapon is one or two-handed. Sometimes it is implied in the weapon name but not always. Spending your hard earned gold on the wrong weapon is no fun at all.

I tried searching for it but the results are flodded with questions on whether to wield one or two-handed weapons which is not what I'm interested in. Is there another way to see this in-game?

Comment: Only certain types of weapons are 2 handed, those types of weapons, will always be 2 handed weapons.  There are a finite amount of those weapons, those items being sold by vendors, identified so they also specifically indicate if they are or are not 2 handed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On PC, there is an explicit note about handedness right there on the item card, in the top right.

[image: Item card]

Anyway, here's the list. Of all weapons that don't explicitly state that they are two-handed, the following weapons are:

- Polearms
- Staves
- Daibos

There are also two-handed Axes, Maces, Swords, Flails and Mighty Weapons, but those also exist as one-handed, and 2H versions always state themslves as, for example, "Two-Handed Flail".

Also Bows and Crossbows are two-handed. But Demon Hunters have an unique ability to equip Quivers to their off-hand, making Bows and Crossbows effectively one-handed for them, and other classes rarely have any reason to equip ranged weapon anyway.

Also, items are listed by handedness here: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/

Comment: Excellent! I checked whether the hand slots are highlighted and it does not appear to be. I have only verified this on the ps3 version so it might be different on PC or other consoles.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain it's the same on PC.

Comment: Game interface differs significantly between consoles and PC... I'll double-check tonight when I start the season and edit.

Comment: Hey folks... The highlight was not heplful (for a Monk it actually highlights both hands for a 1H weapon, because Monk can dual wield), but the item card **does** explicitly say if the weapon is one- or two-handed. Please check on consoles, did we all overlook this? :-)